# Combinação de string em SQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Preciso gerar todas as combinações das palavras de um `varchar` de um registro de um banco de dados.

Preciso desenvolver em `MySQL` em `PostgreSQL`

Para ficar mais simples:

**TABELA DADOS_BASE**

[image: 1]]

Como fazer um procedure/function que selecione os registros e faça isso:

**TABELA_COMBINADA**

[image: 2]]

Ou seja, detectou 3 palavras, fez a combinação de 3 fatorial destas, gerando uma FK refereciada ao ID (PK)

Considerando que a TABELA DADOS_BASE tem N linhas e que esta tem uma string de n palavras, já estou considerando que terá um número grande de linhas geradas na nova tabela.

Sendo assim, qual seria a melhor maneira para para executar esta "query" que seja possível fazer em um servidor em nuvem (por exemplo agendamento execução) de forma que em caso de parar, seja retomado do ponto até onde executou?

Comment: A sua duvida é em relação a lógica ou a estrutura de uma function ?

Comment: Olá Vitor... 

A lógica em si.. tá tranquila, mais ou menos que tentei detalhar pelo resultado esperado.

O grande problema é transformar isto em uma Function ou mesmo procedure, para depois agendar.

Vou utilizar de um servidor mySQL dentro do HotsGator para processar, o que pretendo fazer isto "offline", pois a análise combinatória será grande..

Te garanto que em VBA conseguiria tirar de letra, mas direto no BD é muito mais poderoso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver o problema com recursividade (`WITH`) e filtrar apenas as permutas que possuem exatamente 3 elementos:

```
with recursive ar as (select string_to_array('TENHO UMA DUVIDA', ' ') as ar),
 cte as (
      select
        array[el] as els,
        array_remove( ar, el) as ar
     from
        ar
    cross join
        unnest(ar) as el
  union all
      select
        els || el, array_remove(ar, el)
      from
        cte
     cross join
           unnest(ar) as el
 )
select els from cte AS c
where array_length(c.els, 1) = 3
```

Saída:

```
|------------------|
|              els |
|------------------|
| TENHO,UMA,DUVIDA |
| TENHO,DUVIDA,UMA |
| UMA,TENHO,DUVIDA |
| UMA,DUVIDA,TENHO |
| DUVIDA,TENHO,UMA |
| DUVIDA,UMA,TENHO |
|------------------|
```

Sua função ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_gerar_combinacoes(_frase TEXT)
RETURNS setof TEXT[] AS
$$
    DECLARE
        npalavras INTEGER;
        palavras TEXT[];
    BEGIN
        palavras := string_to_array(_frase, ' ');
        npalavras := array_length(palavras, 1);
    RETURN QUERY
        with recursive ar as (select palavras as ar),
         cte as (
              select
                array[el] as els,
                array_remove( ar, el) as ar
             from
                ar
            cross join
                unnest(ar) as el
          union all
              select
                els || el, array_remove(ar, el)
              from
                cte
             cross join
                   unnest(ar) as el
        )
        select els from cte AS c
        where array_length(c.els, 1) = npalavras;
END;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Testando:

```
SELECT
    permuta
FROM
    fc_gerar_combinacoes('TENHO UMA DUVIDA') AS permuta;
```

[Solução PostgreSQL no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/50349)

[Referência SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522791/all-permutations-of-an-array)

Comment: E o perguntador some.

Answer (score -2):

Segue um esqueleto de uma Function em `PostgreSQL`:

```
create type RET_TEXTO as (
  RIdentificador numeric(18,0),
  RTexto varchar(500)
);


create or replace function MONTAR_TEXTO(
) returns setof RET_TEXTO as $$
declare
  Dcl_TextoID numeric(18,0);
  Dcl_TextoText varchar(500);

  MyCur refcursor;

  result RET_TEXTO;
begin

  open MyCur for select ID, tx_texto from tb_texto ;
  loop
    fetch MyCur into Dcl_TextoID, Dcl_TextoText;    
    exit when (not found);

    result.RIdentificador := Dcl_TextoID;
    result.RTexto := Dcl_TextoText;

    /*Implementar aqui a Lógica */


    return next result;

  end loop;
  close MyCur;

  return;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

**Edit:**

E para utiliza-la seria desta forma:

```
Select * from MONTAR_TEXTO()
```